# Extracting string in BASH using grep

Tags: bash, grep

I`m a bit new to bash, so it might be simply task. What I need is to extract the TITLE from file which contains lines like this one:

> Title:   Blaze Of Glory                 Track: 3

All I need is just a regular expression using grep or sed.
Guess I would figure it out myself, but I`m a bit in hurry:<

Appreciate your help!

Comment: grep can match. it won't extract for you.

Comment: How would you determine where the title ends?

Comment: Did you think that Stack Overflow is a magical code generator? Or that we would just _do it for you_ because you're "a bit in [a] hurry". No, son. No no.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like this:

```
title=$(awk -F: '/^Title/{print $2}' file)
echo $title
```

Output:

```
Blaze Of Glory Track
```

Comment: Please do not encourage this nonsense by answering it.

Comment: Note that what appears to be the next _field label_, `Track`, is also included in the output.

Answer (score 0):

This is just to clean up then answer form Mark.  (removes space in front and track info)

```
title=$(awk -F: '/^Title/{gsub(/(^Title: | Track:.*$)/,"");print}' file)
echo $title
Blaze Of Glory
```

Or to make sure all spaces/tabs etc are gone:

```
awk -F: '/^Title/{gsub(/(^Title:[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*Track:.*$)/,"");print}'
```